# malloc implementation : checking for correct allocation alignment

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dmalloc

my latest test is failing, but i think i've found a solution to pass it. it involves using alignof(max_align_t) (or even alignof(long double)), but i'm not entirely sure if my understanding of allocation alignment is correct..

my idea is that if the actual size of my type is not divisible by the address position, i need to add some padding until the condition is satisfied. this process helps the compiler access memory more efficiently by creating a predictable pattern!

if i'm right, so why the last test is not passing? otherwise, clarification would be appreciated!

```cpp
void *malloc(size_t sz, const char *file, int line) {
  (void)file, (void)line; // avoid uninitialized variable warnings
  if (default_buffer.pos + sz > default_buffer.size) {
    // Not enough space left in default buffer for allocation
    gstats.nfail++;
    gstats.fail_size += sz;
    return nullptr;
  }
  // Here i'm checking for correct allocation alignement
  if (default_buffer.pos % sz != 0) {
    default_buffer.pos += default_buffer.pos % sz;
  }
  // Otherwise there is enough space; claim the next `sz` bytes
  void *ptr = &default_buffer.buffer[default_buffer.pos];

  default_buffer.pos += sz;
  gstats.ntotal++;
  gstats.total_size += sz;
  return ptr;
}
```

test.c

```cpp
int main() {
double* ptr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
assert((uintptr_t) ptr % alignof(double) == 0);
assert((uintptr_t) ptr % alignof(unsigned long long) == 0);
assert((uintptr_t) ptr % alignof(std::max_align_t) == 0);

    char* ptr2 = (char*) malloc(1);
    assert((uintptr_t) ptr2 % alignof(double) == 0);
    assert((uintptr_t) ptr2 % alignof(unsigned long long) == 0);
    assert((uintptr_t) ptr2 % alignof(std::max_align_t) == 0);
    
    free(ptr);
    free(ptr2);

}
```

[image]

I've already solved the problem, and I want to understand why an alternative to my solution is not working on a specific test. So basically, I'm seeking to ensure my understanding is correct!

Comment: You're not passing any type information to your "malloc"; merely the size.  Your code assumes that "alignof" is the same as "sizeof" which is often not the case.

Comment: `pos += pos % sz;` does not align to `sz`. You need to do `pos = (pos + sz - 1) & ~(sz - 1);` assuming `sz` is a power of 2. This only guarantees alignment of `pos` as an index in your buffer. It does not account for the buffer's own alignment. But if you aligned your buffer to `sizeof(max_align_t)` then you should be ok.

Comment: Note on the above, I didn't read quite correctly that you're not actually using an alignment value and just relying on `sz`. For that, you'll need to calculate the most appropriate alignment for `sz` _as a power of two_ and then align to that.

Comment: @paddy so if sz is a  power of 2 then i need to calcculate the alignment for it, and otherwise should  i find the nearest power of two and use that for alignment?

Comment: Yeah, the naive way is to start at 1 and keep shifting left until you reach `sizeof(max_align_t)` or equal/exceed the allocation size. A smarter way is to compute the log-base-2 of your size and trim it to the max alignment, which would probably be faster.

Comment: @paddy: Use `_Alignof (max_align_t)`, not `sizeof(max_align_t)`. Also, using a space between `_Alignof` or `sizeof` and its parentheses operand may help remind programmers that it is an operator, not a function, and the thing after it is a parenthesized type name, not an argument list.

Comment: @paddy: Re “… keep shifting left until you reach … or equal/exceed the allocation size”: An object’s alignment is not greater than the greatest power of two that divides its size. E.g., if an object’s size is 12 bytes, its alignment requirement is at most 4 bytes. There is no need to go to 16. The greatest power of two that divides `size` may be calculated as `size & -size`.

Comment: Why do you have a file named `test.cc` in a question tagged C? `.cc` is for C++ source files, and C++ has different rules than C.

Comment: Whoah, that's a cool trick. Thanks also for clarifying the alignment requirements. That makes much more sense. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Naming your routine `malloc` makes the program’s behavior not defined by the C standard and may have problems with the compiler unless you take precautions to disable built-in compiler knowledge of `malloc`.

Comment: i've changed the name of my function just to clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your alignment calculation is not correct. Imagine you want an alignment of 4, and the residual of modulo is 3. You would not add another 3 -- you would add 4 *minus* 3.

Instead of using modulo, the typical way to align a value is to add one less than the alignment (so that everything except zero is guaranteed to result in an address at the next alignment boundary), and then mask off all the bits lower than the alignment:

```
pos = (pos + align - 1) & ~(align - 1);
```

Note that `align` *must* be an unsigned power of 2.

Since you're trying to align a position in a buffer here, you must also be careful that this actually results in the same alignment in memory.

Regarding automatic alignment, the user [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) also commented:

> An object’s alignment is not greater than the greatest power of two that divides its size. E.g., if an object’s size is 12 bytes, its alignment requirement is at most 4 bytes. There is no need to go to 16. The greatest power of two that divides `size` may be calculated as `size & -size`.

So, putting all this together here's a simple way you can align to an arbitrary address:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

size_t max_align(size_t size)
{
    size_t alignment = size & -size;
    return ((alignment - 1) & (sizeof(max_align_t) - 1)) + 1;
}

void* align(void* ptr, size_t alignment)
{
    return (void*)(((uintptr_t)ptr + alignment - 1) & ~(alignment - 1));
}
```

Note the dirty trick for trimming down to `sizeof(max_align_t)`. This may or may not be better than simply introducing a branch. I'm not much of a bit-basher!

See it in action:

```
void test(char* buffer, size_t size)
{
    size_t alignment = max_align(size);
    char* aligned = align(buffer, alignment);
    size_t offset = aligned - buffer;
    printf("-align=%p size=%zu alignment=%zu offset=%zu\n",
        aligned, size, alignment, offset);
}

struct foo {
    int a;
    char b[2];
    int c;
    void* d;
};

struct __attribute((packed)) bar {
    int a;
    char b[2];
    int c;
    void* d;
};

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[256];
    for (size_t offset = 0; offset < 64; offset += 13) {
        char* base = buffer + offset;
        printf("\nbuffer=%p :\n", base);
        test(base, sizeof(struct foo));
        test(base, sizeof(struct bar));
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
buffer=0x7ffc98db0770 :
-align=0x7ffc98db0770 size=24 alignment=8 offset=0
-align=0x7ffc98db0770 size=18 alignment=2 offset=0

buffer=0x7ffc98db077d :
-align=0x7ffc98db0780 size=24 alignment=8 offset=3
-align=0x7ffc98db077e size=18 alignment=2 offset=1

buffer=0x7ffc98db078a :
-align=0x7ffc98db0790 size=24 alignment=8 offset=6
-align=0x7ffc98db078a size=18 alignment=2 offset=0

buffer=0x7ffc98db0797 :
-align=0x7ffc98db0798 size=24 alignment=8 offset=1
-align=0x7ffc98db0798 size=18 alignment=2 offset=1

buffer=0x7ffc98db07a4 :
-align=0x7ffc98db07a8 size=24 alignment=8 offset=4
-align=0x7ffc98db07a4 size=18 alignment=2 offset=0
```

Comment: As you alluded to in the comments, you could probably use something like `_BitScanReverse64` (msvc) or `__builtin_clzll` (gcc) here instead of the while loop.

Comment: Turns out that's not necessary, because my approach of aligning to the object's size was incorrect. I edited accordingly. Note that the alignment calculation might possibly over-estimate alignment. In my code example, `max_align(sizeof(struct bar))` returns 2, but the built-in `alignof(struct bar)` actually returns 1 because it's a packed struct.